# Durandal - Run datePicker after the DOM activated

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, durandal, durandal-2.0

I added a data picker inside a textbox (that should hold the selected date), it should activate when i press the textbox.
the HTML code:

```
<input type="text" class="textboxes" data-bind="value:request().ExpiredDateTO"  id="tbToDate" />
```

when i press the textbox the date picker doesnt work BUT when i run:

```
$("#tbToDate").datepicker();
```

in the Console of Chrome, it works fine.
i placed the jQuery script inside the

```
self.activate
```

but yet.... it works only when i run the script in the console.

Comment: can you post a fiddle elaborating just a little bit more including your viewmodel?

Answer (score 0):

if anybody need it in the future... i found the answer...
i used  Deferred :
[Defferd  - mozilla article (very good)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Promise.jsm/Deferred)

and
[jQuery api](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/)

i have an activate function and i added the Deffered at the begining:

```
   self.activate = function (data) {


    var deferred = $.Deferred();.....
```

and i put in the end of the activate the:

```
        //run the scripts when evry thing else is done 
        deferred.resolve().then(function () {
            $.datepicker.regional['he'];
            $("#tbToDate").datepicker();
            $("#tabs").tabs();
        });
    });
    return deferred.promise();
```

statement.
it makes the job done.

Comment: Just to confirm, do you need to call .datepicker() every time the DOM refreshes? So each time the text box reloads you need to re-apply the datepicker using jQuery? If that is what you are doing then I can show you a much more elegant way :)

Comment: hi need to call it every time the DOM refreshes...
ca you show the elegant way?

Answer (score 0):

A better solution would be to create a custom binding handler for this. Then the functionality would be reusable and you could even (optionally) set the localization.

```
ko.bindingHandlers['datepicker'] = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var region = valueAccessor();
        if (region) {
            $.datepicker.regional[region];
        }
        $(element).datepicker();
    }
};
```

Then use it in your template like so:

```
<input type="text" class="textboxes" data-bind="value: request().ExpiredDateTO, datepicker: 'he'" id="tbToDate" />
```